# R create a column to identify the group that row belong to

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

Description of Data: Dataset contains information regarding users about their age, gender and membership they are holding.

Goal: Create a new column to identify the group/label for each user based on pre-defined conditions.

Age conditions: multiple age brackets :

```
18 >= age <= 24, 25 >= age <=30, 31 >= age <= 41, 41 >= age <= 60, age >= 61

Gender: M/F

Membership: A,B,C,I
```

I created sample data frame to try out creation of new column to identify the group/label

```
df = data.frame(userid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12), 
                 age = c(18, 61, 23, 35, 30, 25, 55, 53, 45, 41, 21, NA),
                 gender = c('F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', '<NA>', 'M'),
                 membership = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'I', 'I', 'A', '<NA>'))

   userid age gender membership
1       1  18      F          A
2       2  61      M          B
3       3  23      F          A
4       4  35      F          C
5       5  30      M          C
6       6  25      M          B
7       7  55      M          A
8       8  53      M          A
9       9  45      M          I
10     10  41      F          I
11     11  21   <NA>          A
12     12  NA      M       <NA>
```

Based on above data there exist `4 * 2 * 5` options (combinations)

Final outcome:

```
   userid age gender membership GroupID
1       1  16      F          A    1
2       2  61      M          B   40
3       3  23      F          A    1
4       4  35      F          C    4
5       5  30      M          C    5
6       6  25      M          B    3
7       7  55      M          A   32
8       8  53      M          A   32
9       9  45      M          I   34 
10     10  41      F          I   35

   userid age gender membership  GroupID
1       1  18      F          A    1
2       2  61      M          B   40 
3       3  23      F          A    1
4       4  35      F          C    4
5       5  30      M          C    5
6       6  25      M          B    3
7       7  55      M          A   32
8       8  53      M          A   32
9       9  45      M          I   34
10     10  41      F          I   35
11     11  21   <NA>          A   43 (assuming it will auto-detec combo)
12     12  NA      M       <NA>   46
```

I believe my calculation of combinations are correct and if so how can I use dplyr or any other option to get above data frame.

Use multiple if conditions to confirm all the options?

In `dplyr` is there a way to actually provide conditions for each column to set the grouping conditions:

`df %>% group_by(age, gender, membership)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options,

#### One, more automated;

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse""), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)   
df %>% mutate(ageCat = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, 24, 30, 41, 60, Inf))) %>%
     mutate(GroupID = group_indices(., ageCat, gender, membership)) %>% select(-ageCat)
#>    userid age gender membership GroupID
#> 1       1  18      F          A      2
#> 2       2  61      M          B      9
#> 3       3  23      F          A      2
#> 4       4  35      F          C      5
#> 5       5  30      M          C      4
#> 6       6  25      M          B      3
#> 7       7  55      M          A      7
#> 8       8  53      M          A      7
#> 9       9  45      M          I      8
#> 10     10  41      F          I      6
#> 11     11  21   <NA>          A      1
#> 12     12  NA      M       <NA>     10
```

#### Two, more manual;

Here I make an illustration of a solution with category `1` and `4`, you have to code the rest yourself.

```
df %>% mutate(GroupID = 
  ifelse((age >= 18 | age > 25) & gender == 'F' & membership == "A", 1, 
  ifelse((age >= 31 | age > 41) & gender == 'F' & membership == "C", 4, NA)
              ))
#>    userid age gender membership GroupID
#> 1       1  18      F          A       1
#> 2       2  61      M          B      NA
#> 3       3  23      F          A       1
#> 4       4  35      F          C       4
#> 5       5  30      M          C      NA
#> 6       6  25      M          B      NA
#> 7       7  55      M          A      NA
#> 8       8  53      M          A      NA
#> 9       9  45      M          I      NA
#> 10     10  41      F          I      NA
#> 11     11  21   <NA>          A      NA
#> 12     12  NA      M       <NA>      NA
```

the data structure in case others feel like giving it a go,

Comment: Almost presented a `cut` solution. That's good. another approach is `case_when`

Comment: Will this handle `NA` in any of the columns?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, Could you be more specific? I used the data you provided and produced the desired output. You should test it on your 0production data or rework your reproducible example.

Comment: @EricFail Just edited the question to reflect what i mention.

Comment: It should work with `NA` too. Again, you test it on your production data.

Comment: trying to figure out why `must be 1d atomic vectors or lists`. df contains many other columns.

Comment: if I subset the columns (userid, age, gender, membership) to a different df and execute the code works but not on the original `df` that contains few more columns other than the ones involve

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base `R` only, you could do something like this:

```
# 1
allcombos <- expand.grid(c("M", "F"), c("A", "B", "C", "I"), 1:5)
allgroups <- do.call(paste0, allcombos)   # 40 unique combinations

# 2
agegroups <- cut(df$age, 
               breaks = c(17, 24, 30, 41, 61, 99), 
               labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
# 3
df$groupid <- paste0(df$gender, df$membership, agegroups)
df$groupid <- factor(df$groupid, levels=allgroups, labels=1:length(allgroups))
```

1. `expand.grid` gives you a data.frame with three columns where every row represents a unique combination of the three arguments provided. As you said, these are 40 combinations. The second line combines every row of the data frame in a single string, like `"MA1", "FA1", "MB1", etc`.
2. Then we use `cut` to each age to its relevant age group with names 1 to 5.
3. We create a column in `df` that contains the three character combination of the gender, membership and age group which is then converted to a factor, according to all possible combinations we found in `allgroups`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
setDT(df)[,agegrp:= ifelse((df$age >= 18)  & (df$age <= 24), 1, ifelse((df$age >= 25)  & (df$age <= 30), 2, ifelse((df$age >= 31)  & (df$age <= 41),3,ifelse((df$age >= 42)  & (df$age <= 60),4,5))))]
setDT(df)[, group := .GRP, by = .(agegrp,gender, membership)]
```